# Edge browser when refreshing maintains values for ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-edge

I am having issues in Edge whereby when I refresh a page which has some values selected from a `<select>` it still maintains them on refresh.

I have a create-react-app. Currently using 16.8.0 version of ReactJS.

Other browsers are fine just Edge not behaving as expected. Might be down to caching but sure how we can overcome that in the react app

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] in order to help.

Comment: Which kind of Edge browser version are you using? Please explain more details about the maintains value, whether they are the default set value or the selected value? Based on the code in [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), I create a sample on my side (using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0), it seems that if I refresh the page, it will maintain the default set value (in Chrome and microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0). Besides, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).